# How to embed ChatBot(Power Virtual Agent) to Sharepoint online Site

Tags: sharepoint-online, chatbot

I have an embeded code of power virtual agent(chat bot).This bot has to be deployed across the sharepoint online site.

How can I deploy this across the site.
Please help.

Comment: you can work with SPFx webpart, embed iframe code which you can get during publishing PVA chatbox and finally add SPFx webpart onto SharePoint site page.

Answer (score 0):

This link will help you getting started with a ChatBot(Power Virtual Agent) to Sharepoint online Site

https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-fx-webparts/tree/master/samples/react-bot-framework